# Code does not compile in Visual Studio (error A2008)

Tags: assembly, compiler-errors, masm

I have a .asm project and when I try to compile it in Visual Studio, it shows me this error: `Unable to start program, the system cannot find the file specified.`

I also did all the settings, I added msvcrt.lib and legacy_stdio_definitions.lib in Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies, and in  Linker->System->SubSystem I have SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE. Also in Build Dependencies, I selected masm. And I have these errors:

```
1>Suma.asm(1): error A2008: syntax error : .
1>Suma.asm(2): error A2008: syntax error : .
1>Suma.asm(3): error A2008: syntax error : .
```

My code is:

```
.MODEL FLAT, C
.STACK 100h
.DATA
n1 SDWORD 10
n2 SDWORD 13
sum SDWORD ?
.CODE
main PROC
mov eax , n1
add eax , n2
mov sum , eax
ret
main ENDP
END
```

Comment: 32bit?  Or 64bit?  I [don't believe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/dot-model?view=msvc-170) 64bit supports `.MODEL`.

Comment: I think it s 64bit

Comment: IDK why you'd get an error on line 3,  `.DATA`, that should be valid in a 64-bit build, unlike the first 2 lines, unless it's case sensitive?  It's also weird that it calls it a *syntax* error on just the `.`.  That's valid syntax, just maybe a directive that it doesn't recognize.  Anyway, definitely try removing the first 2 lines.

Comment: If you right-click on the suma.asm in the solution explorer and select "Properties", what does it show for *Item Type*?  *Microsoft Macro Assembler* would be the right answer.